# Personalizing Styles

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, tcdl, profiling

*I've suggested that using Tridion localization works for handling certain variations for visitors, but can get [difficult to manage if this is really for personalization](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/localization-personalization-why-cxm-shouldnt-affect-your-sdl-tridion-blueprint-much).* As an alternative to **localizing templates and style sheets**, I'm considering
Profiling and Personalization (PnP) or SmartTarget (ST).

**Can PnP or ST Component Presentation display in non-visible markup (`<head>`)?**

For PnP, having different personalization per site would require Page localization. To avoid this , could developers instead add TCDL tags manually via Page Templates (e.g. `<tcdl:TargetGroup>`)?

**Edit**: removed suggestions and options to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all just text. Tridion doesn't care whether it's emitting a head or a body. There's no reason why a component presentation can't be used in the head of a web page.

Regarding TCDL tags, it really doesn't matter whether these originate in the page or the page template, as long as they are correctly present in the output by the time the TCDL is transformed/rendered.

Comment: Agreed. The only limitation of text that's in the <head> section would be that you cannot inline edit it. But it doesn't sound like something you'd want to inline edit anyway.

Comment: Good point, Peter. But indeed, if it's in the head, it's not really "content".

Comment: Good reminder, Peter. If this was page-specific, then I'd suggest Page Metadata so it's fairly easy to set in context. Also with Experience Manager, if we used SmartTarget or just the ADF, we could also get easier ways to preview these "themes" through the Footprint feature. :-)

Comment: through a small amount of CSS sorcery, you can edit the <head> inline. You just need this in a CSS file somewhere: head, link, style{display:block}

Especially if this is 'page-specific' styling, it's not overly terrible to use an inline-style block in the head.